# in Golang, what is the difference between json encoding and marshalling

Tags: go

What is the difference between JSON 'encoding/decoding' and JSON 'marshalling/unmarshalling'?

Trying to learn how to write a RESTFUL api in golang and not sure what the difference between JSON 'encoding' and 'marshalling' is or if they are the same?

Answer (score 77):

- JSON -> String: Marshal
- String -> JSON: Unmarshal
- JSON -> Stream: Encode
- Stream -> JSON: Decode

Marshal and Unmarshal convert a string into JSON and vice versa.
Encoding and decoding convert a stream into JSON and vice versa.

The below code show working of marshal and unmarshal

```
type Person struct {
First string
Last string
}
func main() {
    /* This will marshal the JSON into []bytes */

    p1 := Person{"alice", "bob"}
    bs, _ := json.Marshal(p1)
    fmt.Println(string(bs))

    /* This will unmarshal the JSON from []bytes */

    var p2 Person
    bs = []byte(`{"First":"alice","Last":"bob"}`)
    json.Unmarshal(bs, &p2)
    fmt.Println(p2)

}
```

Encoder and decoder write struct to slice of a stream or read data from a slice of a stream and convert it into a struct. Internally, it also implements the marshal method. The only difference is if you want to play with string or bytes use marshal, and if any data you want to read or write to some writer interface, use encodes and decode.

Answer (score 18):

Generally, encoding/decoding `JSON` refers to the process of actually reading/writing the character data to a string or binary form. Marshaling/Unmarshaling refers to the process of mapping `JSON` types from and to `Go` data types and primitives.

Actual encoding can include things like serializing unicode characters for example. I think they may be used somewhat interchangeably in documentation sometimes because they generally occur in the same step. The Marshal function for example, will determine which JSON type to marshal something to, and then it will be encoded in string form (which may include other details such as special characters if its textual data).

You can consult the go json package docs for more details on how the [marshaling](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal)/[unmarshaling](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal) steps work.

Answer (score 16):

> What is the difference between JSON 'encoding/decoding' and JSON 'marshalling/unmarshalling'?

---

[Marshaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marshalling_(computer_science)) and [Encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) are of course different concepts, better addressed on Wikipedia (or elsewhere). But in short, objects are marshaled into JSON encoded strings.

Also don't let the Golang `json.NewEncoder` / `(json.Encoder).Encode` and `json.Marshal` methods confuse you. They both marshal objects into JSON encoded strings. The difference being the Encoder, first marshals the object to a JSON encoded string, then writes that data to a buffer stream (or [Data Buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_buffer) on Wikipedia). The Encoder therefore, uses more code and memory overhead than the simpler `json.Marshal`.

You can also see this in the Golang source code:

- Marshal: https://golang.org/src/encoding/json/encode.go?s=6458:6501#L148
- Encode: https://golang.org/src/encoding/json/stream.go?s=5070:5117#L191

Typically, if you need to send the JSON encoded string to a file system, or as an HTTP response, you may need the use of a buffer stream. However, you can also send this JSON encoded string without a buffer stream using a [pipe](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Pipe).

Comment: Thank you for your good answer. what is the meaning of streaming here? I can't understand how a JSON file can be streamed.

Comment: @Arsham - "streaming" here means to put into a buffer stream, sorry for the confusion, I've updated the language on my question. Even if you stream a JSON encoded string chunk by chunk, you still need the entire encoded string to finish streaming before you can unmarshal.

Answer (score 1):

Although there are some good answers to it. I want to summarize the difference between `Encoding/decoding` and `Marshaling/Unmarshaling` below. In some cases, you may use `Encoding/decoding`, otherwise, `Marshaling/Unmarshaling` could be used.

- `Encoding/decoding` JSON refers to reading/writing the character data to a string or binary form.

  - Use `NewEncoder` when working with request or response bodies since they are `Reader`s and it saves you a step of turning it into a byte array to use with `Marshal`
  - The encoder also gives you some additional control like being able to error on unknown fields, which `json.Unmarshal` does not do.
  - If you want indented JSON in some cases (by configurations, for example), then you can `SetIndent(true)`. Also, the `json.Encoder` has `SetEscapeHTML` option
- `Marshaling/Unmarshaling` refers to mapping JSON types from and to Go data types and primitives.
- Memory Usage:

  - If you're decoding large JSON data and already have it all in memory, `json.Unmarshal()` might be slightly faster since there's no intermediate buffering as in the Decoder.
  - If you're reading from a stream (like an HTTP response or a file) and the JSON data can be large, `json.NewDecoder().Decode()` would be more memory-efficient as it doesn't load the entire data into memory.
- Handling Extra Data:

  - `json.Unmarshal()` If there's extra data after decoding the main JSON object/array, it returns an error.
  - `json.NewDecoder().Decode()` Ignores the extra data after decoding the main JSON object/array. You'd have to call `Decode()` again to process the next JSON entity.

Source [1](https://medium.com/wesionary-team/difference-of-json-encoding-vs-marshaling-and-json-decoding-vs-unmarshaling-1a6baf6a7f5c) [2](https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/ajzl98/jsonmarshal_or_jsonnewencoderwencode/)

Answer (score 0):

func Encode is a method on an Encoder, which writes JSON encoded Go types to an output stream (func NewEncoder takes an io.Writer and returns a *Encoder).

Your Go types enter the black box and are written out to the stream in JSON formatting.

Marshal is a function that returns JSON encoding of Go types.

Here your Go types enter the black box and come out of the box in JSON formatting.

It's well documented at: 
[golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/)

Answer (score 0):

There is not a lot of difference between these methods, it's more depends on your usage,
If you have io.Reader (for example: when you are working with HTTP or file system), it's easier to use NewDecoder:

[image: json.NewDecoder go standard lib]

It gives io.Reader and returns *Decoder type,
then you chain a Decode method to it:

[image: json.Decode go standard lib]

And this Decode method will write data to v that you passed to it as a parameter.

### On the other hand

Unmarshal method will help you easily convert stringified JSON to Go data types (mostly structs and maps)

[image: json.Unmarshal go standard lib]

for more details, you can read the documentation:

https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal

https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#NewDecoder

https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Decoder.Decode